# Forgot password email template (custom) issue | Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, email-templates, forgot-password

I have overridden the default email template for "forgot password"

> vendors/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_new.html

When I click the "forgot your password?" link from frontend, the old(default )email template is getting received in the mailbox every time but when I click "reset password" button from the customer account page in admin, I receive the new email template. The new template is placed in the theme folder at:

> app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/email/password_new.html

What do you think could be the reason and remedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured,

**Forgot Email Template** is called on frontend password reset call, which is:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_rest_confirmation.html

whereas, **Remind Email Template** is called on backend password reset call, which is:

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_new.html

Reset Password Template (once you set) is called when the customer changes password in his account.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is correct

`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password_new.html`

overwrited by

`app/design/frontend/PackageName/ThemeName/Magento_Customer/email/password_new.html`

Guess you need to flush cache and static files first.

You can debug in backend.
Marketing -> Communications -> Email Templates -> Add New Template (Just for preview)

Select Template "Forgot Password" and Load Template to check the result.

[image]

Comment: My custom template is not loading when I selected the "Forgot Password" template from dropdown as you suggested. FYI: I have overridden the welcome email template too and its template is loading and working as expected. Flushed static files/cash too